# How to convert MyResult<MyData> to MyData?

Tags: ios, swift

Cant convert `Result<Data>` into `Mydata`

```
struct GetData {
    struct Request {
    }

    struct Response {
        var result: Result<Data>
    }

    struct ViewModel {
        var content: Content<Data>
    }
}

public enum Result<T> {
  case success(result: T)
  case failure(userError: UserError)
}
```

I have declared above code , my view controller contain

```
var mymodel: Data
```

I want to pass my `GetData.Response.result` to  my model above

got an error `Result<Data>` cant pass to `Mydata`?

Comment: Try your struct name with different instead of Data because of Data is a **public struct** of **Foundation** class.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an enum so you need to get to `Data` you need to get to `.success`

```
switch result.result {
case .success(let data):
    // here you have result unpacked
    mymodel = data
case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
```